# DefaultValue properties deserialization

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm trying to deserialize stream to object with default value properties and protobuf-net just ingores this properties when they are missing in the stream. Do i need to manually set before deserialization all properties to their default values or that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DefaultValues` behavior (not just in protobuf-net - in `System.ComponentModel` *generally*, for example `PropertyGrid`, `PropertyDescriptor`, etc) is that this is used to indicate things that *don't need* to be serialized, because they will be defaulted to that same value automatically. As such, it assumes that if your code annotates a `DefaultValue`, then *your code* will be assigning those defaults. This could be in a constructor, field-intializer, or in a pre-deserialization callback (all 4 standard callback points are supported).

Technically, it would not be impossible for the library to explicitly assign these values prior to deserialization - but simply: that isn't what is coded currently.